# How to deregister a class entry from Metaclass?

Tags: python, python-2.7, singleton, metaclass

I am using **Method 3: A metaclass** from [Creating a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python) for creating object from singleton class.
Now depending upon certain event, I want to delete this singleton object and remove its entry from dictionary maintained by metaclass.
How I can do this (without making any change in Singleton class) ?

Here is code snippet for better understanding:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class MyClass():
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init__(self, val1):
        self.val1 = val1

obj1 = MyClass(10)
print obj1.val1

del obj1

obj2 = MyClass(20)
print obj2.val1
```

Output:

```
10
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the dictionary on the metatype:

```
del type(MyClass)._instances[MyClass]
```

or more direct:

```
del Singleton._instances[MyClass]
```

Demo:

```
>>> obj1 = MyClass(10)
>>> print obj1.val1
10
>>> del obj1
>>> obj2 = MyClass(20)
>>> print obj2.val1
10
>>> del obj2
>>> del type(MyClass)._instances[MyClass]
>>> obj3 = MyClass(30)
>>> print obj3.val1
30
```

Comment: ohh yes.. there is nothing `private` in python!